# mean and sd in censored normal distribution with R - which package?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I would like to estimate mean and standard deviation from a series of censored normal distributions in my data in R. Do you suggest any particular package in order to do it?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What do mean with "censored"? Or do you mean "centered"?

Comment: No, I mean that I don't observe the full distribution but just the central interval of a normal, because the tails are not disclosed

Comment: But if the distribution is censored in asymmetric way, the mean and standard deviations of normal distribution do not correspond to the mean and standard deviation of the censored normal distribution

Comment: ditto on `enparCensored()`....unless your censored distribution is of time in which case you'd want to explore the survival package

Answer (score 1):

Check this package from the University of  Pennsylvania:
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/EnvStats/html/enparCensored.html